# Pygame sprite crossing s creen

Tags: python, pygame

The issue is when i press the left or right key while i press it, the sprite crosses the left and right boundaries of the screen. But when i tap it, it will not cross only when i hold the key continuosly

this is the class for the humanship

```
class Human:

y = display_height * 0.8
x = display_width * 0.45
width = 120
image = pygame.image.load('yasin/alien1.png')

def run(self):
    gameDisplay.blit(Human.image, (Human.x, Human.y))
```

This is the main loop which iterates throughout the game

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        gameExit = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            if human.x > 0:
                x_change = -8
            else:
                x_change = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            if human.x < display_width - human.width:
                x_change = 8
            else:
                x_change = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 0
human.x += x_change
human.run()
```

Comment: Did you set the pygame.key.set_repeat()?  When the keyboard repeat is enabled, keys that are held down will generate multiple pygame.KEYDOWN events. 

When pygame is initialized the key repeat is disabled.

Comment: i tried adding that to the intialialisation, game loop, and inside the for event loop (since i dont know where its meant to go, i put it in all places) unfortanetly does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Move the `if human.x > 0:` and `if human.x < display_width - human.width:` out of the event loop because they'll only be executed once per event in the event queue. Rather check in the main while loop if the player is still inside of the game area, otherwise stop it.

I've also changed a few more things: The attributes should be defined in the `__init__` method to make them instance attributes instead of class attributes. Use `self.x` instead of `Human.x` in the class. The `x_change` and `y_change` variables belong to the human object, so they should be attributes as well. Then you can add an `update` method to the `Human` in which you do the bounds checking and the movement.

```
import pygame


display_width, display_height = 640, 480

class Human:

    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('yasin/alien1.png')
        self.y = display_height * 0.8
        self.x = display_width * 0.45
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0
        self.width = 120

    def run(self, gameDisplay):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.x_change
        # Check if the human is outside of the game area.
        if self.x < 0:
            self.x_change = 0  # Stop it.
            self.x = 0  # Reset the position, so that we can move again.
        elif self.x > display_width - self.width:
            self.x_change = 0
            self.x = display_width - self.width


def main():
    pygame.init()
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    human = Human()

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    human.x_change = -8
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    human.x_change = 8
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    human.x_change = 0

        human.update()

        gameDisplay.fill((30, 30, 30))
        human.run(gameDisplay)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: i tried what u put, but now the sprite seems to not move at all

Comment: I can't help you if you don't show me the code (a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). You can post a new question or edit this one.

Comment: its quite big, so is it fine if I email it to you?

Comment: Try to reduce the code as explained on the [mcve page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then either post a new question or add the code to this one. Also, check if you call the `update` methods of your sprites in your main while loop. You have to call `human.update()` every frame or the sprite can't move.